# Spip - Passing data from Javascript to hidden input value

Tags: javascript, spip

J'm trying to pass some data from javascript to #ENV in hidden input value, in CVT form.
In the form i have some radio inputs which are working fine and one hidden input to get the leaflet coordinates stored in js variable.
My input looks lick that:

```
<input value='#ENV{localisation, #GET{coord}} 'name="localisation" type="hidden"></input>
```

and my code:

```
[(#SET{coord, JSON.stringify(latlng_tab)})];
```

In the

```
console.log (#ENV{localisation, #GET{coord}})
```

I can see the coordinates but it doesn't work in input.
Can someone help me, please.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone will be looking for an answer.
I had to remove #GET from input and #SET from the code and instead i'm using that:

```
<input  id="localisation" value='' name="localisation"  type="hidden">
</input>

var latlng_str = document.getElementById("localisation");
latlng_str.value = JSON.stringify(latlng_tab);
```